# Entity Framework DbContext is NOT disposed using dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

***I have the following setup in a solution:***

**EDIT: Demo solution can be found** [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/969714e148ee59c46b7197474937820720200327142904/0bb78301311eb26a42666d401a8977e620200327143008/ddf5da)

ASP.NET Core Web API:

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMyService _service;
    public MyController(IMyService service)
        {
             _service = service;
        }
}
```

Service layer:

```
public class MyService: IMyService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IDataContext _context;
    public MyService(IDataContext context)
        {
             _context = context;
        }
}
```

Entity Framework Core:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext, IDataContext, IDisposable
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options, IAuthenticationService authentication, ILogger<DataContext> logger) : base(options) 
        {
            ...
        }
}
```

A 'CompositionRoot' to link it all together using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection:

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>  options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("myConnection")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
//EDIT: removed this line
//services.AddTransient<IDataContext, DataContext>();
```

This all works as expected but my DataContext is never disposed. I've added logs in the dispose methods to monitor this behaviour but I can't figure out why this is happening (or not happening in this case).
I've tried

- reordering 'AddTransient' without success (as expected)
- using 'AddScoped' instead of 'AddTransient'

I'm using an interface to mock the DbContext in my unit tests, but I want my DbContext to be disposed to.
**Anyone an idea on why this happens and how to solve it?**

EDIT: some extra logs

- 2020-03-24 21:09:29.5727|Options injected in DataContext
- 2020-03-24 21:09:29.6064|Authentication injected in DataContext
- 2020-03-24 21:09:29.6064|Logger injected in DataContext
- 2020-03-24 21:09:29.6262|**Created DataContext 1ddd98a1-a8f9-4096-8a11-c0b4d40d01ae**
- 2020-03-24 21:09:30.1918|Logger injected in CustomerService
- 2020-03-24 21:09:30.2200|DataContext injected in CustomerService
- 2020-03-24 21:09:30.2300|Mapper injected in CustomerService
- 2020-03-24 21:09:30.2482|Authentication injected in CustomerService
- 2020-03-24 21:09:30.2482|**Created CustomerService 5b446267-d908-4291-9918-af1841324708**
- 2020-03-24 21:09:30.2769|Logger injected in CustomerController
- 2020-03-24 21:09:30.2769|CustomerService injected in CustomerController
- 2020-03-24 21:09:30.3186|CustomerController.GetCustomer(4)
- 2020-03-24 21:09:35.0599|**Disposing CustomerService 5b446267-d908-4291-9918-af1841324708**

EDIT march 25:
I've tried using the DataContext without an interface but the problem still exists. I realy have no clue what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: DI is a lot like "managed code" is for memory - the DI container gets to decide when (or if) an object is "disposed".  ALSO: simply making one injected object (e.g. a service) dependent on another (e.g. a DBContext) could affect the latter.  See [Captive Dependencies](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/)

Comment: I understand, I even added the serviceLifeTime to the DataContext but without succes. All other services are Transient as far as I can see.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but for ref. For me, i was overriding the Dispose method, while I should override the DisposeAsync method.

Answer (score 2):

You are not registering the DbContext correctly

Use the following overload of `AddDbContext`

```
services.AddDbContext<IDataContext, DataContext>(options =>  
    options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("myConnection")));
```

Which will associate the interface/abstraction with the concrete implementation.

And remove the transient registration

```
services.AddTransient<IDataContext, DataContext>();
```

Comment: This works but does NOT solve the problem. I've removed services.AddTransient<IDataContext, DataContext>(); and everything works like before. I've added some logs in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Also faced with this issue (is it actually issue?). I have ASP.Net Core WebApi project (framework = net 5.0) and use [AddDbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#scoped) to inject it to the MVC-Controller. It should add db-context as "Scoped" according to the article. As per my expectations, in this case db-context should be instantiated per every http request (that's it) and be disposed implicitly, in scope of MVC-Controller lifetime - but it's does not happen for some reason.. Potencially, it may result in "[The instance of entity type {} cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value {} is already being tracked.](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12459)" (it's a reason why I have come here)

I belive, it may be fixed by added "using" construction in the code or by callind Dispose() from the Controller like that

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing = true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Controller dispose.");
            _dbContext.Dispose(); //your db-context (injected in controller)
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

but not sure it's rigth solution..

Comment: seems like anyone didnt faced with this..

Comment: Where do you add this please? I'm facing a similar issue in a winforms project with Microsoft Dependency Injection - though in my case, I don't think anyone uses DI with winforms so far!

Comment: I added this inside of my Controller class, because in Asp.net core it is [IDsiposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller?view=aspnetcore-7.0). But eventually, I figured out that this approach is not correct and solved this issue by another way.

In your case, as you deal with winforms (and uses DI with threm...OMG) I would suggest you

Comment: to try [IServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicescopefactory.createscope?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) approach. Your can controll yourself when your DI service should be disposed.