# DbContext not Disposed using dependencyinjection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dbcontext

In its most simple form, i created a new mvc core project, and created a class:

```
public class Test : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

registered it

```
services.AddScoped<Test>();
```

and used it in the constructor of a controller

```
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, Test t)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
```

When i set a breakpoint at Test.Dispose(), it is hit as expected after loading the home page.

Now i change the Test class as follows:

```
public class Test : DbContext
{
    public override void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

Now Disposed is not called anymore... Why is this???

I also tried

```
services.AddDbContext<Test>();
```

instead of AddScoped, but that makes no difference.

What do i need to change to make the container call dispose as it did in the first situation?

(related [Question without answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60838175/entity-framework-dbcontext-is-not-disposed-using-dependency-injection))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `Dispose(bool)` method rather than the (usually) non-virtual `Dispose()` method. Try this:

```cs
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
// implementation
}
```

And set a breakpoint to see if it hits. There's more info abotu the difference here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose

Comment: Im using EntityFrameworkCore, it has no Dispose(bool) method that I can override.

Comment: Altough you did set me on the right track. It has a method DisposeAsync, which is called. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In case a class implements both `IDisposable` and `IAsyncDisposable`, MS.DI prefers to call `IAsyncDisposable` whenever possible. This means that it will rather call `DisposeAsync` and skip `Dispose` altogether. This happens when you call `IServiceScope.DisposeAsync`.

In the context of ASP.NET Core, the request's `IServiceScope` will be disposed asynchronously, hense the absense of the call to `Dispose`.